# Revision logging in SVN

Tags: svn

I update my ~/.subversion/config with the following info:

```
[miscellany]
enable-auto-props = yes

[auto-props]
*.php = svn:keywords=Id
*.js = svn:keywords=Id
```

Currently on commit it shows only latest commited revision in file as

```
/* 
* @author David Ordal, david -at- ordal.com
* @version $Id: test.php 3 2009-04-28 05:20:41Z dordal $
*/
```

I want to enable revisions logging in my file so that it look below snippet whenever I commit my code to SVN:

```
/*
@author David Ordal, david -at- ordal.com
@version $Id: test.php 3 2009-04-29 04:20:41Z dordal $
@version $Id: test.php 2 2009-04-28 02:20:41Z dordal $
@version $Id: test.php 1 2009-04-27 01:20:41Z dordal $
*/
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible with Subversion. What you're asking for is a variation on [this FAQ answer](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#log-in-source), which says that nothing like this will ever be implemented in Subversion.

The information you're looking for is already in the Subversion log, keeping it in the file is redundant and may get out of sync with the repository (making it untrustworthy). If you **must** have it in your files, insert the information into them as part of a build/packaging process (you'll have to code this yourself).